# How to open a `cmd` window from nodejs

Tags: node.js

Both of these start `cmd` in the background and I can't see the cmd window:

```
var cp = require('child_process');
cp.spawn('cmd');
```

and

```
var cp = require('child_process');
cp.exec('cmd');
```

I want to get into a state where I can see this window:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the one you're spawning to spawn another one that you can see, using the `/c` or `/k` option and `start`:

```
var cp = require('child_process');
cp.spawn('cmd', ['/C', 'start cmd.exe']);
```